# Issue with Codility challenge in C

Tags: c, pointers

I've been attempting some Codility demo problems for a bit of fun but am stuck on the following simple pointer issue (doh!). I was wondering whether someone might be able to help me?

My code is:

```
struct Results solution(int N, int A[], int M) {
    struct Results result;

    N = 2;
    const int N_const = N;
    int counter[N_const];

    counter[0] = 2;
    counter[1] = 4;


    result.C = counter;
    result.L = 2;
    return result;
}
```

Where the struct is defined as:

```
struct Results {
  int * C;
  int L;
};
```

However, it returns:

> Returned value: [136343560, 1]

not the [2, 4] I was expecting

Now, what's really confusing me, as I'd expect the above is a pointer issue on my part, is the following works:

```
struct Results solution(int N, int A[], int M) {
    struct Results result;

    int counter[2];

    counter[0] = 2;
    counter[1] = 4;


    result.C = counter;
    result.L = 2;
    return result;
}
```

Correctly returns:

> Returned value: [2, 4]

BUT the following doesn't:

```
struct Results solution(int N, int A[], int M) {
    struct Results result;

    int counter[10000];

    counter[0] = 2;
    counter[1] = 4;


    result.C = counter;
    result.L = 2;
    return result;
}
```

Incorrectly returns:

> Returned value: [0, 0]

I feel that I'm missing something obvious. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

The `counter` array is on the stack and so it "ceases to exist" (aka goes out of scope) when the function returns. The counter in the returned struct is pointing to some space in the stack the contents of which can change at any time.

There are plenty of good descriptions that go deeper into the issue.

Comment: Ahh, I thought it would be something silly on my part! This is the problem with attempting these late at night. It was the consistency of the returned values that threw me off of the right path.

Thank you very much for your help John.

Answer (score 0):

I confused with usage of counter and struct.

Here is one approach to update and return the struct data (this avoids duplicate of data (memory optimization)).

```
struct Results solution(int N, int A[], int M) {
    struct Results result;

    //here allocated length of 2 bytes (you can define variable for length and replace 2 with variable)
    result.C =(int*)(malloc(2*sizeof(int)));
    result.L = 2;   
    memset(result.C, 0, 2*sizeof(int));  

    //perform the operations and update directly result.C array.
     //-or in this example case updating two bytes
    result.C[0] = 2;
    result.C[1] = 4;
    result.L = 2;

    return result;
}
```

Elaborate the problem if you are looking for something specific.

Answer (score 0):

Put your array outside of the function solution and it will work because it is global then. ;)

Otherwise the array will disappear when solution is finished.

Or you can just declare it as static.

```
static int counter[100000];
```